# Oracle Database Exception

Tags: oracle

I dont understand much in oracle. But I get the following oracle error.

```
ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception
```

ORA-06512: at "TARET.GUI_PKG", line 847
ORA-06512: at line 1
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception
ORA-06512: at "TARET.GUI_PKG", line 847

I am updating my table by inserting this: ALL_TAB_COLUMNS

The full sql query isnt important, it is a simple update query that updates a column.

Why am I getting that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your "packages" in oracle. Look for the package named "TARET". Inside you will find "GUI_PKG". There, the creator of that procedure has thrown a user-defined exception I am guessing.

Comment: Is there a reason for that error to occur. It throws the error only on this function: ALL_TAB_COLUMNS

Comment: Your `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` explanations are inconsistent. In the question you say "I am updating my table by inserting this: ALL_TAB_COLUMNS" but in the comment above you say "this function: ALL_TAB_COLUMNS". What is `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`? Note that there's a dictionary view with the same name. I'd recommend showing the code that's triggering the error.

Comment: I think TARET will be the schema and GUI_PKG the name of the package. Check line 847 of the GUI_PKG to see what is causing the error

Comment: No I think they way the packages work in oracle is a package contains various procedures etc so its notation is generally PACKAGE.PROCEDURE. Although it could not be a package at all...